# Angular 2 styleUrls not applied

Tags: css, angular, materialize

I started learning Angular 2. I have a problem when using extenal css for Components.
It works fine when I hard-code the style in the html tag itself. But the css is not applied when loaded via external css using `styleUrls`

If the css worked then the image would resize to 250px and `p` tags font-size would be 50px .But both dint happen

Attaching my Plunkr

https://plnkr.co/edit/j1GrrI5NMHSXqgdgECH4?p=preview

**app.html**

```
<div class="carousel carousel-slider center" data-indicators="true">
  <div class="carousel-fixed-item center">
    <a class="btn waves-effect white grey-text darken-text-2">Skip To Site</a>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item accent-color white-text" href="#one!">
    <div class="row">
      <img src="http://materializecss.com/images/yuna.jpg" alt="Profile Pic" class="circle responsive-img slider-profile-pic">
    </div>
    <p class="slider-text white-text">Hello There</p>
    <p class="slider-text white-text">Welcome To My Website</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item accent-color white-text" href="#two!">
    <p class="slider-text white-text">Second Panel</p>
    <p class="slider-text white-text">This is your second panel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item accent-color white-text" href="#three!">
    <p class="slider-text white-text">Third Panel</p>
    <p class="white-text">This is your third panel</p>
  </div>
  <div class="carousel-item accent-color white-text" href="#four!">
    <p class="slider-text white-text">Fourth Panel</p>
    <p class="slider-text white-text">This is your fourth panel</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**app.css**

```
.carousel-slider {
  height: 100vh;
}

.slider-profile-pic {
  width: 250px;
}

.slider-text {
  font-size: 50px;
}
```

**app.ts**

```
import {Component, NgModule, OnInit} from '@angular/core'
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

declare var $: any;

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.css']
})
export class App implements OnInit {
  name:string;
  constructor() {
    this.name = 'Angular2'

  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    $('.carousel.carousel-slider').carousel({ fullWidth: true });
  }

}

@NgModule({
  imports: [ BrowserModule ],
  declarations: [ App ],
  bootstrap: [ App ]
})
export class AppModule {}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your css is not applied due to the css of the carousel.

The css selector of the carousel images is `.carousel .carousel-item img` and your css selector is `.slider-profile-pic`. Your css selector is less specific, therefore the carousel's css is applied.

You can force your css with `!important`:

```
.slider-profile-pic {
  width: 250px !important;
}

.slider-text {
  font-size: 50px !important;
}
```

Comment: I know that using !important will work ..But why it is not working

Comment: The css selector of the carousel images is `.carousel .carousel-item img` and your css selector is `.slider-profile-pic`. Your css selector is less specific, therefore the carousel css is applied.

Comment: I got it..If you add that as the part of answer.I'll accept it